# Remove DC comp offset of AC current

Tags: ac, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, current-source, dc-offset

I am attempting to build a circuit that excites a sensor which requires an AC current of ±1mA and 20kHz frequency. For this, I used voltage to current converter integrated circuit XTR110, which is controlled by a sine wave generator. However, this IC can only produce a positive current, so the output is AC current with DC offset. To ensure that the sensor is excited only by ±1mA current, I added an inductor of 39mH between the output terminals of IC and a capacitor of 100nF in series with the sensor to completely remove the DC offset as shown in the schema.

[image: Circuit]

The sensor is represented by the R_Loud in the schema. I got an AC current with no DC offset flowing through the R_Loud. However, the peak to peak of the AC current is affected by the resistance of the R_Loud. In other words, when the resistance of the R_Loud increases, the AC current reduces.

is there another way to remove the DC offset and ensure a stable AC current?!
Or, is there another integrated circuit that can provide a negative current as well?!

Note: I'm not an electrical engineering specialist

Comment: Did you already try directly connecting the sine wave generator to the sensor? If the sensor has 200 Ohms of resistance, as shown, the 200 Ohm resistance will convert voltage to current all by itself. Most sine wave generators can drive a 200 Ohm load.

Comment: I used 200ohm resistance just for clarification. The resistance of R_Lound changes with time, and can reach higher values.

Comment: OK, well it seems like you should replace the inductor with a constant current source (DC current source) or find a voltage to current converter that can sink and source current and does not need an offset.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for this kind of voltage-to-current converter?!

Comment: Well, a voltage to current converter is called a transconductance amplifier. You could try searching for that, or by the abbreviation TCA. You want one that is sink/source capable. The term for a TCA that can both sink and source current is "bipolar." So you can search for bipolar TCA and maybe you will find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the inductor is creating a parallel load with your resistor + capacitor. This means that the current will be split between the two.

You can remove the inductor and use a big capacitor to couple the AC component only.

You’re also shorting the dc component to ground with an inductor, which is a bad idea

Comment: How much big this capacitor should be?!
How can I know the adequate capacitor for my case and how it should be connected?!

Comment: There has to be a DC path to ground for the voltage to current converter.

Comment: You should be able to use 100nF, but I can't say for sure. You can download a model for the XTR110 here https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/332834/xtr110-spice-model